# Solution to manage 2 applications on a single url?

Tags: java, nginx, web-applications

I have 2 different web applications. One is standard jsp/java based web-app deployed on tomcat. Other a php webapp managed using NGINX. I want them to be referred(also they should refer each other) through single context url.

I was thinking if proxypass will be good enough solution. I am unaware of network level solutions so if anyone can suggest something.